# I want to improve my overall PHP

Tags: php, mvc

I've taken criticism before on my PHP and have since then taken the improvements into my routine. However, I still believe that I can improve.

I believe that SE is the best place for the best programmers. If any of you are bored enough to tell me what I can do better, I'd appreciate it greatly.

You can see a small project of mine, using pretty basic PHP here: 
https://github.com/OutThisLife/Fae-Studio---Finances -- the site is http://finance.faestudio.com/

Very basic PHP, but I believe it holds most of what I usually do across the board. MySQLi, OO PHP, an MVC-type system.

The MVC-type system was one of the improvements that was suggested. Am I doing it right?

The page that controls the entire project:

```
require('classes/autoloader.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    $file = @$_GET['u'] ? $_GET['u'] : 'tasks';
} else {
    $file = 'login';
}

$T = new Template($file);

// Load by-page controllers
$T->controller($T->file);

// Set menu
$T->menu = $T->getModule('menu');
$T->pagename = $T->file;
$T->jscall = ucwords($T->file);

$T->render();
```

Template Class:

```
class Template {

    public 
        $file; // filename

    private 
        $template, // placeholder
        $data; // stored variables

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->template = self::_s('wrapper');
        $this->file = $file;

        $this->data['LOAD'] = self::_s($this->file);
    }

    public function __set($key, $val) { $this->data[$key] = $val; }
    public function __get($key) { return $this->data[$key]; }

    private function replaceAll() {
        foreach($this->data AS $key => $val)
            $this->template = str_replace( /* {TAGS} are simple variables */
                '{'.$key.'}', 
                $val, 
                $this->template
            );

        self::clean();
    }

    public function fillInData($array) {
        foreach($array AS $key => $val) $this->$key = $val;
    }

    private function clean() {
        $regex = '/{([^{|}]\S*)}/'; // all {tags} w/o spaces
        $this->template = preg_replace($regex, NULL, $this->template);
    }

    public function render() {
        self::replaceAll();
        echo $this->template;
    }

    public function getModule($file, $dir = 'modules') {
        return self::_s($file, $dir);
    }

    public function _s($file, $type = 'views') { // quick file_get_contents
        return file_get_contents($type.'/'.$file.'.php');
    }

    public function controller($file) { 
        $filepath = './controllers/'.$file.'.php'; 
        if(file_exists($filepath)) 
            include($filepath);
    }

}
```

Example of how I am handling my controllers:

```
global
    $T;

$tasks = new Tasks();
$T->num = $tasks->taskCount;

// Pending task HTML output
if(is_array($tasks->pending)): foreach($tasks->pending AS $r):
    $T->pending_tasks .= '
        <label class="task">
            <input type="checkbox" name="done[]" rel="'.$r['id'].'" /> 
            <code>'.@money_format('$%i', $r['cost']).'</code> &mdash; 
            '.$r['title'].'
        </label>'."\n";
endforeach;
else:
    $T->pending_tasks = '<label class="task"></label>';
endif;

// Completed task HTML output
if(is_array($tasks->completed)): foreach($tasks->completed AS $r):
    $T->completed_tasks .= '
        <label class="task complete">
            <input type="checkbox" name="done[]" rel="'.$r['id'].'" checked="checked" /> 
            <code>'.@money_format('$%i', $r['cost']).'</code> &mdash; 
            '.$r['title'].'
        </label>'."\n";
endforeach;
else:
    $T->completed_tasks = '<label class="task"></label>';
endif;
```

Class example:

```
class Tasks {

    private
        $db,
        $uid;

    public
        $pending,
        $taskCount,
        $completed;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = DB::getInstance();
        $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

        $this->getTasks('pending');
        $this->getTasks('completed');
    }

    private function getTasks($key) {
        switch($key):
            case 'pending':
                $query = '
                    SELECT id, title, cost
                    FROM tasks
                    WHERE (
                        status IS FALSE
                        AND uid = \''.$this->uid.'\'
                    ) ORDER BY cost DESC
                ';
            break;
            case 'completed':
                $query = '
                    SELECT id, title, cost
                    FROM tasks
                    WHERE (
                        status IS TRUE
                        AND uid = \''.$this->uid.'\'
                    ) ORDER BY id DESC
                    LIMIT 7
                ';
            break;
        endswitch;
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        if(!$result) die($db->error);
        else {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $r[] = $row;
            if($key === 'pending')
                $this->taskCount = $result->num_rows;
            $this->$key = $r;
        }

        $result->close();
    }

}
```

The view for the above controller:

```
<header>
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
</header>
<div id="main" role="main">
    <form id="cev" class="basic_data">
        <code><strong>{num}</strong> pending tasks</code>
    </form>
    <br />
    <h2>Pending</h2>
    <div id="pending_tasks">
            {pending_tasks}
    </div>
    <div id="add_task">
    <span id="add_new_task_link">Add New Task</span>
    <form method="post" action="/">
        <label for="new_task_title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="new_task_title" id="new_task_title" />
        <br /><br />
        <label for="new_task_cost">Amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="new_task_cost" id="new_task_cost" />
        <br /><br />
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
        &nbsp; <a href="#" id="cancel_new_task">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</div>
<br />
<h2>Completed</h2>
 <div id="completed_tasks">
    {completed_tasks}
</div>
```

Comment: The title of your post should be the function/purpose of your code.

Answer (score 4):

I've not reviewed the whole piece of code yet but I spotted two things right away just three lines in.

```
$file = @$_GET['u'] ? $_GET['u'] : 'tasks';
```

There are two problems with this.  The first is the use of @ to suppress errors.  This is considered bad practice a lot of a time, because it can hide errors that are needed for you to debug the application.  Your live and staging environments should be set up with display_errors off, and in your dev and test servers you want to see errors as they happen.  It apparently also hurts performance.

The second, and FAR more serious problem, is you're trusting data input from an outside source, in this case $_GET.

I cannot overstress what a serious error this is, it can leave your system wide open to being hacked, destroyed, forced to expose private data or to trigger a denial of service attack.  Probably 9 out of 10 bugs in PHP code (or any code in fact) are down to programmers trusting data to contain what they expect it to.

In this case, all an attacker has to do is type the url of your script and add ?u=/etc/passwd et viola, he now has a list of all the users on your server along with hashes of their passwords.  If anyone has chosen a weak password (hint: Someone on your system will choose a weak password), then they can brute force the hash and recover the password, then log into your server with access to all that user's files and with all that user's privilages.  If the user in question has high level access (or God forbid is root), then you're really screwed.

Always follow the Fox Mulder principle when you are dealing with input from outside your programs, in otherwords TRUST NO ONE!  Never accept that the contents of $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE and so on contain nothing that could cause you harm.  Always validate all input.

Comment: `Fox Mulder principle` - Nice! Good review, +1

Comment: @GordonM: All good stuff :) - but I don't think the risks here are as bad as all that: in the Template class the OP does this in the constructor:

    public function _s($file, $type = 'views') {
        return file_get_contents($type.'/'.$file.'.php');
    }

So by default it's loading variants of views/whatever.php

Maybe I'm missing something but some variant of this seems pretty normal practice in front controller MVC. Probably a good idea to filter for special characters and strip them out of the input string, but I don't see a problem with the basic approach.

Comment: $_GET is controlled via mod_rewrite and only allows certain variables; in this case, tasks/client/stocks/history. Anything else would be denied by the htaccess.

Comment: @TalasanNicholson: Assuming that is a fatal mistake.  Don't EVER assume that $_GET contains safe data. A well meaning sysadmin may disable .htaccess files at some point in the future without you knowing, should that happen you'll be wide open.

Answer (score 2):

Some quick thoughts:

1. Overall I think this is mostly quite nice code but has some issues
2. Using global $T in controller? Don't like single letter variable names for this, and why not pass the object into the controller instead of using global to get at it? Dependencies should be injected into the class, it shouldn't go out and grab stuff from wherever it wants.
3. You're building HTML in the controller; I think this should be in the view or in a view helper
4. Don't like this:

   ```
   $result = $this->db->query($query);
   if(!$result) die($db->error);
   ```

   I don't think you should ever use die() in production code. This will cause a white screen of death for the user - unpleasant - and depending on your error settings could expose the SQL error and information about your query if there's a problem on the production site - unpleasant and a security risk. Surely better to throw an exception, catch it, log an error and display a sensible error screen to the user
5. Inconsistent use of _ in front of private method names. Personally I dislike it, but if you're going to do it, you should do it consistently. And using single letter names again forces one to go and read what the method does to understand what it is, making the code significantly less readable
6. Method names in my opinion are more readable if they're based on verbs; mostly you've made good names but Template->controller might be better if it was loadController or something. More to the point though, why is the template loading a controller in the first place? Shouldn't the controller load the template?

I think you might run into problems if you had to add in support for RSS, XML or JSON later on instead of just loading HTML views and replacing data in them

So maybe have a think about the bigger picture of how you've structured this. I think controllers should retrieve data, decide what sort of output to build, and then delegate the building of the output to something else, which could be the HTML template class or something else